# Serious issue with starting application in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, qt-creator

I have been writing an application for two years in QtCreator. (My application uses some external libs).

Recently I've ported the application into Qt5.3mingw(windows7). The application built successfully but failed to start within QtCreator and gave "The program has unexpectedly finished.".

With debugging the application, it gives this error message: "During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135".

However the application starts succussfully outside of QtCreator! It seems the QtCreator has severe problem in starting the application or it's the linker problem.

I've even uninstalled all Qt and QtCreators and re-installed them, but the problem insists.

Any guide will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming Windows because that looks like a Windows error code. At least in some contexts I think that error code means *0xC0000135: STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND*. Could this possibly be, because you are now using "Shadow build" (default), but weren't before? Anyway, try printing the application directory at start of main function, then copy the external lib DLLs there.

Comment: @hyde Yeah it's windows. Already the problem will be fix if I copy the external libs dlls in the application directory. But I have linked the external libs in the .pro file and for two years this was working perfectly!

Comment: Then there are the usual Windows tools for tracking this: Dependency Walker (depends.exe) and Process Explorer (procexp.exe), which you can download from MS.

Comment: Well, previously the DLLs were so that they could be found. Perhaps you previously had these DLLs in PATH, or had copied them to Qt DLL directory but forgot, or had copied them to the directory where application was built before, or whatever. Windows DLL finding is a bit of a WTF really (such as, using global PATH to find libraries)

Answer (score 4):

Status code `0xC0000135` is `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`.

There's some DLL that your program is dependent on that is not in a directory being searched when launched from the QtCreator IDE.

You may need to make sure the PATH is set correctly for QtCreator.

Also, a tool like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) may be able to help you figure out what DLL is the problem.  I'm not sure why Windows doesn't make it easier to find out what DLL can't be found.